Issues iterating through shared preferences in Flutter
I have a bunch of ids stored in shared preferences as recipeIds. I want to loop through all of those ids and get the strings associated with them in. During my forEach loop, it only adds one id and then quits unexpectedly. Is there another way to get strings from shared preferences?
List<String>? getMainRecipesFromPrefs(SharedPreferences sp) {
  List<String>? recipeIds = sp.getStringList("recipeIDList");
  if (recipeIds == null || recipeIds.isEmpty) return recipeIds;
  List<String>? strRecipes = [];
  print("recipeIds: $recipeIds");
  recipeIds.forEach((id) {
    print("id: $id");
    String? r = sp.getString(id);
    if(r == null) throw Exception("Recipe null"); 
    strRecipes.add(r); 
  });
  if (strRecipes.isEmpty) print("No recipes");
  return strRecipes;
}

This is the testing output:
flutter: recipeIds: [151, 149]
flutter: id: 151

